# no subscription in current account azure - rider

Tags: azure, deployment, rider

I have a subscription of azure and I have created an app service. When I try to connect azure account in Rider(IDE) I'm getting the [error](https://github.com/shuvo3/azure-issue/blob/main/ns.png) **"no subscription in current account"**. I tried to connect with vs code, getting same error. But everything is working fine with a different device.

my account [status](https://github.com/shuvo3/azure-issue/blob/main/ss.png) is active.

note:I used this account with no issue. Getting error after reinstall Ubuntu in my device.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue by clearing cache of IDE.